# installing geojson-vt with Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, geojson, vector-tiles

I need help using the leaflet plugin geojson-vt. According to tutorials, like this one on http://bl.ocks.org/Sumbera/c67e5551b21c68dc8299, there should be a js file called geojson-vt-dev.js. When I download the zipfile from GitHub I get 6 different js files in the src folder: clip.js, convert.js, index.js, simplify.js, tile.js, wrap.js.

Can anyone help me figure out what I am doing wrong?

This page; http://www.paulcflynn.com/projection_picker.html is ultimately what I am trying to speed by using vector tiles. Loading the GeoJSONs straight in leaflet was fine, but now I need to add more vector files, which reduce performance significantly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the section named Browser Builds on the [GitHub page](https://github.com/mapbox/geojson-vt#browser-builds). It shows you how to use [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/) to build a development or minified production build.

I just tried `npm run build-dev` and the output is named geojson-vt-dev.js

Assuming you have git installed, here are the steps:

1. `git clone https://github.com/mapbox/geojson-vt.git`
2. change into the `geojson-vt` directory
3. `npm install`
4. `npm run build-dev`